# Should I reject an edit if it solely adds a language tag that is not necessarily needed?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I asked a question about React, a JavaScript library. A low-reputation user [made an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31404038/revisions), merely adding the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag to my [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) tag. (I accidentally accepted the suggested edit before reverting it.)

I take care not to clutter [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) when I ask a [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) question. Similarly, I don't clutter [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) when I ask a [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) question.

Should I stick to my above-mentioned policy or should I accept scope-expanding edits?

Comment: Generally I tag with the language regardless of what other tags I use. I just assume that it's best for both my and the site's sake to have questions linked to as many relevant searches as possible.

Answer (score 17):

You're making a mistake.

Tags aren't clutter they're part of a categorisation system that enables potential answerers to find your question and people who have the same question in the future to find both the question and its answers.

If you have a question about django and are not tagging it Python only those people specifically searching for django questions will have a good chance of seeing it. Experienced Python developers who can understand django will be far less likely to see the question. This means you're less likely to get a good answer, which isn't in your or the community's interest.

If you tag with incorrect tags just to get additional attention it's not likely to be well received but using the tags that actually relate to the language you're using is not and cannot be a bad thing.

Comment: The other thing is that (from my experience) a lot of questions that are tagged with a framework don't always require specific knowledge of the framework. More, it's just the OP is using that framework but the real problem can be addressed by anyone with an understanding of the base language.

Comment: I thought I'd implied that in this answer @Jon with _"Experienced Python developers who can understand django"_; obviously not strongly enough :-)!

Comment: I was just generalising it :p